# Iterate over string and not over characters of that string

Tags: reactjs, string, loops, character

By now I have the dropdown menu where I want that some strings from JSON file will be placed with checkboxes near every string, and by now I have checkboxes near every character of the strings

The app is built over the React as a client and Express as a server side, here is my codes:

Client:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Spinner, Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleFetchBoth = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:3001/api/getdata`, { query })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data); // Check the response data
        setFetchedData(response.data.data); // Access the wrapped data in response.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row gx-5">
                <div className="col-3">
                  <div className="p-4">
                    {loading && <Spinner animation="border" />}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="input-group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter query here"
                    aria-label=""
                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                    value={query}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                  <div className="input-group-append">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-warning btn-sm gx-3"
                      onClick={handleFetchBoth}
                    >
                      Both
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            {fetchedData && fetchedData.Data && fetchedData.Data.data ? (
              <div>
                <h5>Query: {query}</h5>
                <Dropdown>
                  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="secondary" id="dropdownMenuButton">
                    Select a string
                  </Dropdown.Toggle>
                  <Dropdown.Menu>
                    {Object.values(fetchedData.Data.data).map((dataItem, index) => (
                      <Dropdown.Item key={index}>
                        <input
                          className="form-check-input"
                          type="checkbox"
                          value=""
                          id={`checkbox-${index}`}
                        />
                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={`checkbox-${index}`}>
                          {dataItem}
                        </label>
                      </Dropdown.Item>
                    ))}
                  </Dropdown.Menu>
                </Dropdown>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <p>No data fetched</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/api/getdata', (req, res) => {
  const { query } = req.body;

  const pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['scripts.py', query]);

  let output = '';

  pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    output += data.toString();
  });

  pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code === 0) {
      try {
        const result = JSON.parse(output);
        res.json({
          data: {
            Response: 200,
            Message: 'Data from python',
            Data: {
              data: result
            }
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error parsing JSON output:', e);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
      }
    } else {
      console.error(`Python script error (exit code ${code})`);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  });
});





app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3001');
});
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "google-search",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.4",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
        "next": "^13.4.4",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-perf-devtool": "^3.1.8",
        "react-query": "~3.39.3",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "react-window": "^1.8.9",
        "router": "^1.3.8",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.3",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.85.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.2"
    }
}
```